# most efficient way to get a very smooth player movement in unity5

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

So I am making a simple 2d endless mobile game. In the game, the player object (spaceship) moves upwards continuously and then the player can use either left or right to move the player to avoid obstacles.

As a newbie I am finding it very difficult to achieve a very smooth motion in the player movement. I have watched many tutorials including the unity official tutorials about moving an object. They all use simple techniques like:

`rigidbody.velocity = (new Vector2 (0.0f, 1.0f)) * speed` in the fixedupdate function

or `transform.Translate (velocity * Time.deltaTime * speed)` in the update function

or `rigidBody.MovePosition (rigidbody.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime)` in the fixed update or

just just changing the `transform.position` over time in the update function.

But none of these techniques or code that I have used have helped me to achieve that very smooth motion in the player movement that I want. No matter what I try I still get lags in the player movement. I have also tried switching the rigidbody.iskinematic on and of and changing the rigidbody interpolation but I am still not able to achieve a smooth movement in in 2d games that we see such as [ios games shredd or split the dot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4n3MPXKH9w). I thought that it might be my computer that was very slow or something that is why I am not getting a smooth movement but I transported my project onto my friends computer which is twice as fast and I still have the same results. I also striped all that decided to erase all the code that is in the player controller scripts and just focus on the code for moving the player but the results has not changed.

I am thinking that it is because I am just using a very simple and inefficient code to move the player or it might have something to do with changing some settings in unity. So the question is what is the most efficient way to achieve a very smooth player movement in unity. (Codebase and unity settings.)

Currently I am just using `rigidbody.velocity = (new Vector2 (0.0f, 1.0f)) * speed` to move the player and I have made the camera a child object of the player for simplicity.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried translate using vector2 `transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, 1) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);`. I've recommend to have the fps displayed on your gui so you know if your entire game is lagging or if it is just your player. If your entire game lags, then there is some profiling to be done there...

Comment: BTW, since that code is using `Time.deltaTime` it should be within the `Update` method.

Comment: Where is your code, handy to put up what you have that isn't giving smooth results. It might do with the scale of your object and the amount is moving is less than the amount you have over time. Is your camera moving with the object?

Comment: @DavidEspino actually I did use the `transform.Translate` method and I stated that as well in my post. But it did not work as well. I am now learning about the profiling.

Comment: @Alan-DeanSimonds I am just using `rigidbody.velocity = (new Vector2 (0.0f, 1.0f)) * speed` this code to move the player and I have attached camera to the player as a child object so it will follow the player. Actually talking about the scaling, I scaled the original object to 2.5 for both width and height. can that be the problem? And Also you can share more with us how scaling affects physics and player movement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to interpolate the transform.position. This essentially mathematically smooths out the translation between the two positions.

Something else I've experienced is that the editor is sometimes more laggy than the end product, so I recommend building the game and testing it out to see if that is the case.

Finally, if you are using transform.position to move the object, ensure that the numbers are fairly small. Big numbers obviously make the object jump around a lot more.